# Getting strange issue while running Objective-C framework in Swift Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-framework

Not sure what is the issue, and unable to find on goggle too.
Application screen became black and app crashed.

> -[BSMutableSettings applicationWillResignActive:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13ed05f20
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BSMutableSettings applicationWillResignActive:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13ed05f20

Comment: can you show your code where you tried

Comment: Do you have main.m inside ObjC code? Maybe it's conflicting with your Swift code.

Comment: @JosipB.,No - I don't have that.

Comment: Can you search if someone explicitly calls applicationWillResignActive: method or forwards it's selector? Crash says that someone is trying to send applicationWillResignActive: message to instance of BSMutableSettings but indeed it should be AppDelegate instance. Does your app crash without ObjC library?

Comment: No, it doesn't.
I have added child view controller of my library on actual app's viewcontroller.
Library's childViewController is added beneath navigation bar, now when I click on navigation bar the app crashes.